# Remember size of dialogs

Tags: java, swt

In my application I've a main *shell* window and lots of dialogs (classes `extends Dialog`). I use `setSize(width,height)` when initializing them, but I know that users constantly resize them for their taste.

What is a smarty way to get notified when the size changes so I can store/load them?

(And why don't do toolkit provide such a thing out of the box, like XUL?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most if not all GUI toolkits have a resize event that triggers whenever the user (or something else) resizes a given widget. Some readong for an example [Moving and resizing - SWT](http://book.javanb.com/swt-the-standard-widget-toolkit/ch04lev1sec3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [java.util.prefs.Preferences](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).  The width and height settings can be saved via putInt() and retrieved via getInt().

It would be a pretty minor task to subclass Dialog or JDialog and create a SizeRememberingDialog, or (probably better) to create a SizeRememberer(Dialog) class to set the size when constructed, listen for resize events, and save the new size whenever a resize occurs.